# Prevent rabbitmq from resending messages

Tags: rabbitmq, message

I am using rabbitmq version 3.2.4 on centos 6. I am using it as a work queue and have a few subscribers listening on the queue.
Each subscribers processes a lot of data. Hence, it can take over 30 minutes to process each message.
The messages are just work object outlining what I need the subscribers to execute.

The problem arises when rabbitmq retransmits the same message to a different subscriber after about 25 minutes or so; while the previous subscriber is still processing the message.

How can i prevent rabbitmq from resending the message as the first subscriber hasn't died and it is still processing. I have tried setting/unsetting the heartbeat flag with no avail.

Comment: I did some more digging last night. It appears that the subscriber is loosing the connection to the Q ( probably a socket timeout, I figure )

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you protect from the resending problem by adding a message sequence no into every request.
When receiving the message, to check it is resending or not.