# rabbitmq : set duration for resending message to another consumer

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am using spring-amqp library (over rabbitmq) to process messages from a queue.
There are a number of consumers of the queue. Processing some messages takes time. After about 20-30 minutes into processing of a message, it is  resent to another consumer automatically. Is there a way to avoid / control it ? If so, which property should I use ?

Comment: spring-amqp version is 2.3.2

Comment: Messages are supposed to be (typically) removed from the queue and processed.  Someone might be able to help you with a timeout setting, but a solution that is more in line with the way you're supposed to be using a message queue is to split up your 20 minute processing task into multiple (sequential) subtasks - a pipeline - each with their own queue buffering pending work between them.  Everything shuffles along down the pipeline, and rabbitmq keeps the pending stuff safe while any given worker is only working for a minute (or a few seconds!).

Comment: @davidbak a bigger task been split into smaller ones. One of them is relatively time consuming and it is timing out.

Comment: What you are describing makes no sense. Messages remain in an un-acked state (and won't be sent to another consumer) until the current consumer either acks (and removes) the message or rejects (and requeues) the message (or the connection is lost). The only way I can see what you are describing happening is if the connection to the current consumer is lost for some reason. There is no concept of a "timeout" for message processing.

Comment: @GaryRussell - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283964/prevent-rabbitmq-from-resending-messages which describes the same problem. The connection is not lost. It is fine.

Comment: I suggest you ask the RabbitMQ engineers on the rabbitmq-users Google group. I am sure they will tell you the same as me.

Comment: I'll be interested to know if there's a solution for this along the lines you're looking for (if you find one elsewhere please post it here yourself as an answer) but I think what's going on is that this isn't the use case for RabbitMQ (or messaging systems in general). If you're dealing with tasks that take more than a minute you probably want a different kind of orchestrator - some kind of job/task scheduling system.  If you continue on this route you may very well find other problems down the line, if I'm right that this isn't really the right way to use a messaging system.